# Getting a confusingly complicated mysql request work

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas, sqlite

I'm not an expert in SQL but I recently started using `sqlite3` module in `Python` with databases and together with `pandas` and its `read_sql_query()` they make a pretty nice tool.

Now, say, I have a database looking something like this (I just really made this up for the demo purposes).

```
age iq  married
===============
91  77  0
54  124 1
31  124 0
32  95  0
74  34  0
18  56  0
43  42  0
78  56  0
91  77  1
```

The task is, and this is where it might get slightly confusing. I want to select all the rows (people) with the same IQ as the rows with `married=1` (including married people themselves). So I would like the result to look like this:

```
age iq  married
===============
91  77  0
54  124 1
31  124 0
91  77  1
```

And even in general, let's say I'm even more restrictive and want to select all the people who have the same `iq` AND the same `age` as the married ones. In this case the result would look like this:

```
age iq  married
===============
54  124 1
91  77  0
91  77  1
```

There might be tons of other columns that could or could not be ignored.

Now of course I can do that iteratively, by first selecting the married ones, then comparing the tuples of `(age,iq)`, but that's kinda boring. The question is, is there a neat way of doing this in one shot with the `pandas.read_sql_query()`?

So in short, I'm trying to do something like this (I know this just selects married ones, but it's just an example):

```py
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

connection = sqlite3.connect('people.db')
mydata = pd.read_sql_query(
                """
                SELECT *
                from People
                    WHERE married=1 ... *some magic here*
                    GROUP BY *foo*
                    HAVING *bar*
                """, connection)
```

where I can't really come up with any "magic" to make it do what I want (probably because of poor knowledge of all SQL commands and conditions). Maybe there is a way to do this with nested `SELECT` commands and some things like `IN`, but I'm not really sure.

I feel like there has to be a simple way (or maybe I'm wrong and it's easier to do it iteratively), so I'm asking the community!

Comment: I suggest you provide an example that's a bit more representative of your actual use case.

Comment: Honestly, it's basically this, but with a few GB in the database and with three criteria I need to compare, instead of one or two. Say, `age`, `iq`, `dob`, it's really not that important I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to use an `EXISTS` condition in the `WHERE` clause which asserts that a given IQ value matches at least one other married record:

```
SELECT age, iq, married
FROM People p1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM People p2 WHERE p1.iq = p2.iq AND p2.married = 1);
```

[image]

### Demo

The `EXISTS` subquery might have much better performance with the following index in place:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON People (iq, married);
```

This would allow rapid lookup of a given `iq` value in the table, along with checking the `married` status.m

Comment: That's pretty cool! Works great. Could you explain what this `from People p1` and then `select 1` means? Is that like a kind of a loop like `[x for x in range(10)]`? Or maybe you could just direct me to a proper term to google to know more about this?

Comment: You could starting by reading [this tutorial](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php).  The exists logic checks, for each person, if another person can be found with the _same_ IQ, who is also married.  If so, then this record is added to the result set.  Not that `EXISTS` is generally more performant than `WHERE IN`.

Comment: Ok yes, I think I got it. I got the logic of selection and comparison, I just didn't know you can create subsets by nesting `SELECT`-s. Thanks! And thanks for the tutorial, will read more about that :)

Comment: Ooph, this is actually pretty slow on my real data (probably because it's a nested loop). But thanks anyway, as it seems to work )

Comment: Adding an index on `(iq, married)` should help: `CREATE INDEX idx ON People (iq, married)`.

Comment: Actually, what's the best practice of adding `INDEX` in Python? I could do cursor `connection.cursor().execute("CREATE INDEX idx ON People (iq, married);")` but then second time I access the same database and try to create this index again, it says `index already exists`. So I could of course do `try/except`, but I was just wondering if there's a best practice which would not "save" the index?

Comment: You typically would not add an index from your application language, but rather you would do it directly from SQLite.  If you really don't need the index long term, then just delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
select * from People
where iq in (
    select iq from People
    group by iq
    having sum(married) > 0
)
```

Comment: This is smart. :) But in reality I have a slightly more elaborate data where something like `sum(married)` won't work. Works flawlessly for this case, though.